# Special term for 'intersection' of option price

Tags: options

Suppose, I have written two ordered lists:

$S_{call}= (\textbf{8000, 8050, 8100}, 8150, 8200, 8250)$ and
$S_{put} = (7850, 7900, 7950, \textbf{8000, 8050, 8100})$.

Entities are correspond to strike prices of call and put on the same underlying asset XYZ.

**Update:**

Spot price is equal to $8067.6$, then XYZ 8050 call and XYZ 8050 put are "at-the-money" options, XYZ 8000 call and XYZ 8100 put are "in-the-money" options, and the remaining options would be "out-of-the-money".

How to name strike prices which are marked with bold? Is there a special term?

Comment: Not that I can think of, but it's generally around the forward moneyness that this happens (actively traded contracts).

Comment: @Quantuple, thanks. I think 'crossing prices' or something like this.

Comment: I think these are just common strike prices from the two lists. Or what is called in set theory the intersection of two sets. No special name in connection with options.

Answer (score 2):

I think you might be looking for "in-the-money" for the calls with strikes below spot and the puts with strikes above spot.  And then the options that are close to spot will be called "at-the-money".  And the remaining options would be "out-of-the-money".